# cats and function compositions

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have data types:

```
import cats.Monoid
import cats.implicits._

object Domain {
  case class Money(amount: Double) extends AnyVal {}

  implicit val moneyMonoid = new Monoid[Money] {
    override def combine(a: Money, b: Money): Money = Money(a.amount + b.amount)
    override def empty: Money                       = Money(0)
  }

  case class Operation(account: Account, amount: Money) extends AnyRef
  type Operations = List[Operation]
}
```

I want to implement `totalAmountCalculation` like function composition

```
val calcTotalAmount = map(x => x.amount) >>> combineAll
```

For this I wrote some code:

```
def map[A, B](F: A => B): List[A] => List[B] = (m: List[A]) => m.map(F) 
val combineAll      = moneyMonoid.combineAll _

val calcTotalAmount = map[Operation, Money](x => x.amount) >>> combineAll
```

What cats features I can use for avoid   write Monad  wrapper for use it in functions composition ?

I want to see my code like:

```
map(x => x + 1) >>>
filter(x < 100) >>> 
fold(1)((a,b) => a+b))
```

Comment: *I can use for avoid write Monad wrapper* - Did you mean `Monoid`?

Comment: I mean: For `Monoid` I have some methods like `combine combineAll`, for Monad I have `flatMap, map`, for Foldable 'foldLeft foldRight`. How  can  I easy curry for use it in composition?

Comment: Monads don't compose the same way functions compose.

Comment: it's inspired  ramda.js.

Comment: It's easy to use something `val filterOdd= filter(x => x %2); val sumOdd = filterOdd >> combineAll`

Comment: Maybe something like `Iso` or `Invariant` to translate from monoid on `Double` to monoid on `Money` and `Order.by` to create `Order[Money]` from `Order[Double]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to avoid using the wrapper `Amount` and having to use `x => x.amount` everywhere in your function definitions.

There are a couple of ways to solve that problem. The first would be to use a type alias, as you did for operations. This will naturally give you the default `Monoid[Int]` which has `0` for `zero` and addition for `combine`:

```
allMoney
 .map(_ + 1.0)
 .filter(_ > 3.0)
 .foldLeft(1.0)(_ + _)

// 13.0

allMoney.combineAll

// 12.0
```

Another option would be to use the [`newtype`](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype) library which gives a similar effect using case classes:

```
@newsubtype case class Money(amount: Double)

allMoney
  .map(_ + 1.0)
  .filter(_ > 3.0)
  .foldLeft(1.0)(_ + _)

// 13.0
```